# Loop through row multiplying by one row VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a set of weights in rows `BA40:BZ40` and I want each row starting from `BA60:BZ60` to `sum (BA40*BA60 + BB40*BB60 + ... + BZ40*BZ60)`. Then paste this in `CA60` then move onto row 61. However I still need to reference `BA40:BZ40`. I don't know if its my simplistic mind getting confused or its not possible. However I have learnt everything is possible. My code at the moment is

```
Dim cellsum As Long
For i = 60 to 1000
```

So I want to calculate for each day, the weighted sum of the loss. For example day 1, `sum(0.2*(-10)+ 0.2*(-8)+ 0.1*(-6) + 0.5(-4))`

```
Weight: 20%, 20%, 10%, 50%

Day 1: -10, -8, -6, -5
Day 2: -9, -8, -7, -6
Day 3: -5, -5, -4, -4
...
```

Comment: Why VBA why not a formula? Calculations in formulas is Excel's strength. Can you please provide a screenshot of the data?

Comment: I cant provide a screenshot of the data, however they are daily returns, and for each day, I take the 20 worst performing. Then (according to user input on the other sheet), they input weightings, calculate then generate a large amount of data regarding a weighted basket of these returns, so I can change the weighting of each one. It gives the user flexibility in changing the weighting and the number of stocks.

Comment: What do you mean by `For i = 60 to 1000` what it would do?

Comment: Sorry I mean 24 worst returns. And I have 940 rows of data, so row 1000 is empty. Each row (starting from row 60, is a date.

Comment: Well your question is almost unclear if you cannot provide the original data please provide some analog data, that represents your original data. See [mcve]. More precise information would be extremely helpful otherwise I think your question is to broad to give an answer.

Comment: I have included an example in the question

Comment: @SamHarper Example data helped a lot to understand! Thank you for helping us to help you. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `SUMPRODUCT()` function as following. It will automatically calculate percentage. You do not need to sum as `.2`, `.1`

```
=SUMPRODUCT(BA40:BZ40,BA60:BZ60)
```

Comment: Should be `$BA$40:$BZ$40` otherwise you cannot drag it down.

Comment: Agreed. I just assumed he will show result in a single cell.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine the follwing table:

[image]

Then the weighted sum of day 1 would calculate according to your example like …

```
=SUM($B$1*B3,$C$1*C3,$D$1*D3,$E$1*E3)
```

which is the same as …

```
=SUMPRODUCT($B$1:$E$1,B3:E3)
```

This formula in G3 then can easily pulled/copied down until G5.

---

So for your data it should be something like the following in cell `CA60` …

```
=SUMPRODUCT($BA$40:$BZ$40,BA60:BZ60)
```

and then copy down to the other rows.